Awaiting a response from DB in recursive function
I've got a Javascript class I've written that decodes a nested function system, recursively. When assigning the "value" to the object, in the DB function, it has to do a database call by ajax/post request to a PHP page which does the DB call and returns the value, which then gets assigned to the function object.
Here is an example of the nested function:
IF([DB("client", 2, "dob") > DATE("2024-04-24")], "TRUE", CONCAT$("The report is due on ", DATE$(-4)))

The problem I'm having is that because the DB takes a second to respond, the recursion does the comparison between DB() and DATE() before DB() gets it's value in the promise "then()"
I was able to set async to false and it works great (even the UI pause isn't noticeable), but I want to find a better way.
I've thought about checking the children to ensure they have the values they need and forcing delays as needed till they get a response, but that isn't much different than using synchronous calls.
Here is the class:
    class Function {
        // this.name, this.params, this.defintion, this.function
        constructor(definition) {
            this.definition = definition;
            this.cat = "not a function"; 
            if (this.checkSyntax()) this.cat = "function"; 
            this.checkParam();
        }
        
        checkSyntax() {
            if (this.definition.match(/\^/)) throw new Error("You are not allowed to have '^' in the formula: " + this.definition); // Reject it because it has a '^' char.
    
            const regex = /^([A-Z\$]+)\((.*)\)$/;
            const match = this.definition.match(regex);
            
            if (match) { // We have proper function form. 
                this.name = match[1]; // Extracting the function name
                if (!function_names[match[1]]) throw new Error(match[1] + " is not a valid function name: " + this.definition);
                
                this.params = SpecialSplit(match[2]).map(param => {
                    const trimmedParam = param.trim();
                    return trimmedParam ? new Function(trimmedParam) : null;
                }).filter(param => param !== null);// Extracting and cleaning up parameters
    
                const openParenthesesCount = (this.definition.match(/\(/g) || []).length;
                const closeParenthesesCount = (this.definition.match(/\)/g) || []).length;
                  
                if (openParenthesesCount === closeParenthesesCount) 
                    return true;
                
                throw new Error("The number of parenthesis doesn't match: " + this.definition);
            }
            else 
                return false;    
        }
    
        checkParam()
        {
            if (this.cat != "function") 
            {
                if (this.definition.match(/^\[.*\]$/))
                {
                    this.cat = "[COMPARISON]";
                    var a = parseExpression(this.definition);
                    this.left = new Function(a.pre);
                    this.test = a.test;
                    this.right = new Function(a.post);
                    this.output = "[COMPARISON]"; 
    
                    if (this.left.output != this.right.output && this.left.output != "VARY" && this.right.output != "VARY")
                        throw new Error("Can not compare '" + this.left.output + "' to '" + this.right.output + "': " + this.definition);
                    else if (this.left.output == "DATE" || this.left.output == "VARY")
                        this.value = eval("new Date(this.left.value) " + this.test + " new Date(this.right.value)");
                    else if (this.left.output == "INTEGER" || this.left.output == "STRING")
                        this.value = eval(this.left.value + " " + this.test + " " + this.right.value);
                    else
                        throw new Error(this.left.output + " evaluation has not been programmed: " + this.definition);
    
                    this.eval = this.left.value + " " + this.test + " " + this.right.value;
                }
                else if (this.definition.match(/^"[^"]*"$/))
                {   this.cat = "STRING"; this.value = this.definition.replace(/"/g, ""); this.output = "STRING"; }
                else if (!isNaN(this.definition))
                {   this.cat = "INTEGER"; this.value = +this.definition; this.output = "INTEGER"; }
                else if (this.definition == "TRUE")
                {   this.cat = "BOOLEAN"; this.value = true; this.output = "BOOLEAN"; }
                else if (this.definition == "FALSE")
                {   this.cat = "BOOLEAN"; this.value = false; this.output = "BOOLEAN"; }
                else 
                    throw new Error("Unknown parameter: " + this.definition);
            }
            else 
            {
                var param_string = this.params.map(function(element) { return element.cat === "function" ? element.output : element.cat; }).join(", ");
                var the_formula; 
                var param_options = ""; 
    
                function_names[this.name].forEach(element => {
                    param_options += "<br>" + element["parameters"];
                    var testParts = element["parameters"].split(", ");
                    if (element["parameters"] == "[STRING]") testParts = this.params.map(function() { return "STRING"; });
                    var conditionParts = param_string.split(", ");
                    var match = true;
                    
                    if (testParts.length === conditionParts.length) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < testParts.length; i++) {
                            if (testParts[i] !== "VARY" && testParts[i] !== conditionParts[i]) {
                                match = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        match = false;
                    }
    
                    if (match) the_formula = element;
                });
                if (!the_formula) throw new Error("The function '" + this.name + "' does not have a definition that matches '"+param_string+"'<br><br>Options are: <br>" + param_options);
                
                //this.formula = the_formula;
                this.syntax = the_formula["name"] + "(" + the_formula["parameters"] + ")";
                this.output = the_formula["response"];
    
                switch (this.name)
                {
                    case "DATE":
                        var date = new Date();
                        if (this.syntax == "DATE(INTEGER)") date.setDate(date.getDate() + this.params[0].value);
                        if (this.syntax == "DATE(STRING)") date = new Date(this.params[0].value);
                        this.value = date;
                        break;
                    case "DATE$":
                        var date = new Date();
                        if (this.syntax == "DATE$(INTEGER)") date.setDate(date.getDate() + this.params[0].value);
                        this.value = date.toLocaleDateString('en-CA').replace(/\//g, '-');
                        break;
                    case "IF":
                        if (this.params[0].value) 
                            this.value = this.params[1].value;
                        else
                            this.value = this.params[2].value;
                        break;
                    case "CONCAT$":
                        this.value = concatenateValues(this.params);
                        break;
                    case "DB":
                        var self = this;
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'includes/external_db.php',
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: { 
                                action: "get_column_value", 
                                table: this.params[0].value,
                                id: this.params[1].value,
                                col: this.params[2].value,
                                debug: "false"
                            },
                            async: false, // Setting async to false makes the request synchronous
                            success: function(response) {
                                // Handle success
                                self.value = response;
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                // Handle errors
                                throw new Error("Error accessing the DB: " + xhr.responseText);
                            }
                        });
    
                        
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

class ExpressionPart {
    constructor(pre, test, post) {
        this.pre = pre.trim();
        this.test = test.trim();
        this.post = post.trim();
    }
}
function parseExpression(input) {
    var match = input.match(/^\[\s*(.*?)([<>!=]=?)(.*)\]$/);
    if (match) {
        var pre = match[1];
        var eval = match[2];
        var post = match[3];
        return new ExpressionPart(pre, eval, post);
    } else {
        // If no match found, return null or handle the case accordingly
        return null;
    }
}
function SpecialSplit(paramString) {
    let current = '';
    let depth = 0;
  
    for (let char of paramString) {
      if (char === '(') {
        depth++;
      } else if (char === ')') {
        depth--;
      }
  
      if (char === ',' && depth === 0) {
        current += '^'; // Replace comma with '^'
      } else {
        current += char;
      }
    }
  
    return current.trim().split('^');
}
function concatenateValues(params) {
    var concatenatedValue = "";
    for (var key in params) concatenatedValue += params[key].value;
    return concatenatedValue;
}


Asynchronous code allows the program to continue executing while waiting for requests to complete, enabling better utilization of system resources and improved responsiveness.

"in the promise then()": I don't see any then in your code.

Promise.then() was used in a previous iteration of the code where it wasn't waiting for the response. The code I posted is my most recent version of the code using synchronous code, it achieves the goal but uses the deprecated async = false.
